# Determine if a file is accesible

Tags: c#

I want to determine if a file is accessible to read its contents or write inside; I use this code:

```
public bool Can_access_to_file(string FileIsAccesible_file)
{
    try {
        System.IO.FileStream Stream = new System.IO.FileStream(FileIsAccesible_file, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        Stream.Close();
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have some doubts about it. It does not seem a very good solution because it sets the file stream and that means for big files it will take so long to check, right?

What should I do to improve it?

Please supply or explain a better solution than my current code.

Comment: Other than wrapping it in a using statement, it seems good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping in a using statement ensures resources get cleaned up properly when you are done (+1 Rufus), however more to your question it does not matter the size of the file you are trying to check, as you are only ever initially reading to the set (or default) buffer size.

As you are only opening and closing and have not specified a buffer size (therefore default), you are only ever reading the first 4096 bytes of the file.

If you do not want to wrap in a using statement but still ensure you clean up after yourself, call `Stream.Dispose()` after you call `Stream.Close()`

Comment: its hard to choose between this answer or the Mario's answer, but this is what i need a detailed explanation of how it works the code above to know if using a stream is the best or at least a good solution. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I use to check whether I can open a file exclusively:

```
/// <summary>
/// check whether a file can be accessed
/// --> Warning: No lock is performed, so things may change until you really access the file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fullFilename">name of the file</param>
/// <returns>true if the fle can be accessed, false in any other case</returns>
public static bool CanOpenExclusive( string fullFilename )
{
    Contract.Requires( false == String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( fullFilename ), "fullFilename is required but is not given" );

    try
    {
        using ( FileStream stream = File.Open( fullFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch( IOException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```